# Searching for excel formula that do job in the body

Tags: excel, formula

I have table with pupils that did 6 tasks.
Maximum points are 15 and minimum is 0.
Pupil needs to have 12 points in three tasks so he could get extra 10 points.

For example:
N & S           TASK 1   TASK 2  TASK 3   TASK 4 TASK 5 TASK 6
Name & Surname |     10        15     0        15      15     5

Which formula / function I need to use that will examine does student have done three tasks with maximum points (15) and if he is sum all tasks points and add 10 to all, else just did summary.
There's photo of my table so you can get better view.
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwk89.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CountIF function to count how many cells in the row score 15. You can wrap that in another If statement to see if it is true if your count is above x